# Error when calling a Markov Chain

Tags: python

I'm working on a project that calls a Markov Chain module. I've scraped data and composed a basic text generating file, but keep getting an error that I don't understand. My code looks like:

```
from markov_python.cc_markov import MarkovChain

mc = MarkovChain()
mc.add_file('C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\markov_chain\src\lyrics.txt')
mc.add_string('shape')

print mc.generate_text(10)
```

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\markov_chain\src\run.py", line 14, in <module>
    print mc.generate_text(10) 
  File "C:\EclipseWorkspaces\csse120\markov_chain\src\markov_python\cc_markov.py", line 61, in generate_text
    idx = random.randint(0, len(self.lookup_dict)-1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 244, in randint
    return self.randrange(a, b+1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 220, in randrange
    raise ValueError, "empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)
ValueError: empty range for randrange() (0,0, 0)
```

And here is the code it is calling back to:

```
def generate_text(self, max_length=20):
    context = deque()
    output = []
    if len(self.lookup_dict) > 0:
        self.__seed_me(rand_seed=len(self.lookup_dict))

    idx = random.randint(0, len(self.lookup_dict)-1)
    chain_head = list(self.lookup_dict.keys()[idx])
    context.extend(chain_head)
```

Not sure what to do. Please advise.

Comment: Looks like self.lookup_dict is empty

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I accessed the module from someone else and got it to work. Afterwards I compared them and noticed that I had somehow gotten my indentation out of whack. My IDE wasn't returning any issues with the code, so I didn't think to look at that (still new at this). Running smooth now.